# "Cannot Resolve Hostname" when using Subdomain

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

A group of friends wanted a Minecraft server to play together on, so I went ahead and deployed a VPS, and directed an A record titled `play` to the server's public IP address. I connected to the server via SSH using `play.coffeehousecode.com` as the hostname, and didn't encounter anything out of the ordinary, so I started a Minecraft Server instance, and the logs showed no problems to report.

However, when trying to connect to the server using the Minecraft client, I receive an error stating that the Hostname couldn't be Resolved. I checked my DNS records to make sure everything checks out, and SSH-ed into the server again without a problem. When connecting to the server using it's public IP address, however, I can connect and play without a problem.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you connect to the server through a tunnel?  It might be the server not accepting connections instead of DNS not directing properly to the VPS.  Also, check firewalls and that the server is binding to the proper (or any) address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make an educated guess and say you told them the new address mere minutes after creating the A record, right? That's the source of the problem.

DNS changes take time to propagate across the Internet [due to caching and Time To Live rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dns#Record_caching). If you told them to connect right after you created the A record, it would not yet exist in *their* ISP's DNS servers.

For reference, I can ping your new subdomain successfully and I can connect to it using Minecraft (though it immediately kicks me out because it's whitelisted), so your friends should be able to connect now or soon, unless they use an ISP that is particularly slow to update their records.

Comment: I left my desk for a little under an hour after editing the record and before attempting to log in. I tried logging in again the next morning, and it's working without a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Also: DNS records only need to propagate if a cache has the record. If someone queries for `play.coffeehousecode.com` and it doesn't exist, then that "does not exist" might get cached, and you'll have to wait if you create the record. However, if nobody has ever queried for it, then there is no "does not exist" cache record to wait for. (a DNS cache does know about every domain name.) (So, create the domain name first, then spread the word about it.)